# Display record between today's date and 6 months before

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having trouble with my SQL `SELECT` statement. Basically I want to return all the records where the transaction date is between today's date and today's date minus 6 months.

What i have tried so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM loan_ledger
WHERE trandate <= DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())
```

but it doesn't get the exact result. The result was returning dates like 2009 or 2007, but what I want is, if the date today is April 9, 2012, the results must be transactions from this date (April 9, 2012) to April 9, 2012 minus 6 months (October 9,2011). Only.

What the heck is that the results are displaying transactions on the past and still displaying the 2009, 2001 records which I don't want!

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer are close but if you are using BETWEEN you will want to add one to the date if you want to include today

```
select * from loan_ledger
where trandate BETWEEN dateadd(month,-6,getdate()) AND getdate()+1
```

When using between with getdate, it won't include today unless you at 1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just change you where clause

```
select * from loan_ledger
where trandate >= dateadd(month,-6,getdate()) AND trandate <= getdate()
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

all your where statement is saying is "grab information when the date is before 6mo ago" instead of "grab stuff from 6mo ago to today"

try something like

```
select * from loan_ledger
where trandate BETWEEN dateadd(month,-6,getdate()) AND getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for rows where trandate is <= 6 months ago. Surely every trandate in 2007 fits that criteria.

If you want only trandates [between](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) today and 6 months ago, try

```
trandate between dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) and getdate()
```